# Behavior of invariants under reduction mod p

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

Let $R$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra with an [edit: linear algebraic] action of $G(\mathbb{Z})$ where $G$ is a split simply-connected semisimple group.

Then for any prime $p$ we have a map $R^{G(\mathbb{Z})} \otimes \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow (R \otimes \mathbb{F}_p)^{G(\mathbb{F}_p)}$. Is this map necessarily surjective for sufficiently large $p$?

Comments:
(1) The simply-connectedness assumption may seem weird; it is made to ensure that $G(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow G(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is surjective so that there is a map at all.

(2) If $G$ is a finite group, then the answer is yes by an averaging argument.

(3) If $G$ is unipotent, then the answer is no. For example, take $x \mapsto x+1$ acting on $k[x]$; there are many invariants in positive characteristic (Artin-Schreier covers!).

Comment: Do you mean just an abstract action of $G(\mathbb Z)$, or an algebraic action of $G$?

Comment: Also, how does the averaging in (2) work for orbits of size divisible by $p$?

Comment: Algebraic action. Regarding (2), I'm still referring to the statement for "sufficiently large $p$".

Comment: Compare https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350590/lifting-g-invariants-from-characteristic-p-gg-0-to-characteristic-0-for-a-re/350791#350791.

Comment: If a reductive group is split over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and acts as such on a module, then a root subgroup fixes a weight vector if and only if the $\mathbb{F}_p$ points of the root subgroup fix the vector.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
Let $G=SL_n$, acting on its defining representation $V$, with $n\geq2$.
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ be the obvious $\mathbb{Z}$-form of the ring
of polynomial functions on $V$. Let $p$ be a prime. For any $f\in R/pR$ the
product over all $g\in SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of $f\circ g$ is invariant under
$SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. But there are no nontrivial $G(\mathbb{Z})$-invariants in $R$
because $G(\mathbb{Z})$ has a Zariski dense orbit in $V$.